# Is there a name for a function which produces the same result when reapplied?

Tags: functions

Is there a name for a function which, when applied to its own result, will always return that same result?

e.g.
for a function $f(x) = ||x||$

$f(2.5) = 2$

*and*

$f(f(2.5)) = 2$

Comment: The property is [Idempotence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA post this as answer for me to mark as correct

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would say that the common name is **idempotent**, see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idempotence